# Updating Realm to 0.88.3

Tags: java, android, realm

I have updated `realm` from the version `0.87.2` to `0.88.3` and I'm getting the error below:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{user.temp/user.temp.MainActivity}:
>   io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must
>   be provided

I didn't change anything in the models and I really don't know how to fix this issue.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a empty migration to the `RealmConfigration` so it will give a more detailed message about what should be migrated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Go to your app setting `clear cache` and then `clear data` and then run again**

Hope it helps.